# ROS_CanOpen Ixxat USB to can converter

Tags: ros, can, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to use ros_canopen package to communicate via can. The communication should be done via a USB to can converter from the company Ixxat. Which steps are necessary to use the converter?

Thanks for your answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299879/ros_canopen-ixxat-usb-to-can-converter/) by [Henne](https://answers.ros.org/users/32327/henne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like Ixxat supports SocketCAN for [some devices](https://www.ixxat.com/support/file-and-documents-download/drivers/socketcan-driver).
If you can use that, everything should work as [usual](http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface).

If not, you could provide your own driver plugin for `canopen_motor_node` (for motor drives).
Unfortunately, there is still no support for these plugins in the [bridge nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_bridge) ([Issue](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/252)).

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Henne](https://answers.ros.org/users/32327/henne/) on 2018-08-17**:
Thanks for your answer. The SocketCan driver works. But if I want to compile the canopen package via catkin, then I get an error.
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable_policy.h: error: no match for call to '(const std::hashcanopen::motorbase::operationmode) ...
Followed by many other errors..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:
Are you sure you are compiling the `kinetic-devel` branch? Not the `melodic-devel` one?

**Comment by [Henne](https://answers.ros.org/users/32327/henne/) on 2018-08-17**:
where can i see this? and where can I get the right version?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:
If you've cloned the repository using `git clone`, then a `git status` or `git branch` should show you which particular branch is currently checked out.

If you've downloaded a zip from github, the branch name should be part of the filename.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:
Also: please make sure you actually have to build the packages yourself. Otherwise just use `apt` to install them.

**Comment by [Henne](https://answers.ros.org/users/32327/henne/) on 2018-08-17**:
Thanks for your answer. I downloaded it now as a correct zip file and then it works. When I clone it, it always downloads the melodic version.
Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:\

> When I clone it, it always downloads the melodic version.

No, it downloads *all* versions, but `melodic-devel` is the default branch, so that one is 'active'.

You'll need to `checkout` the correct branch.

But again: make sure you actually need to build things from source.